# Get the number of times an element appears in an array

Tags: excel, vba

How can I count the number of times an element appears in an array ?

E.g. fruits(banana, orange, apple, orange, apple, orange)

I would like to get :
    Banana(1)
    Orange(3)
    Apple(2)

I have tried this:

```
Private Function IsInArray(findMe As Variant, arr As Variant) As Long 
Dim element As Variant 
Dim count As Integer 
count = 0 
   For Each element In arr 
     If element = valToBeFound Then 
       count = count + 1 
       IsInArray = Replace(element & "(" & count & ")", " ", "") 
       Exit Function 

     End If 

   Next element 

End Function
```

Comment: Use a dictionary and set the item to the count of the key.

Comment: or sort-then-walk.

Comment: What have you tried? We can help more if you can show us the code you're working with.

Comment: Do not post additional information in comments. ALWAYS add it to your original post instead.

Comment: Is that all in a single cell or is each fruit entry in its own cell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
Sub test()
    fruitArr = Array("banana", "orange", "apple", "orange", "apple", "orange")
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each Fruit In fruitArr
        sKey = Fruit
            If Not dict.Exists(sKey) Then
                dict.Add sKey, 1
            Else
                dict(sKey) = dict(sKey) + 1
            End If
    Next Fruit
    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Debug.Print key, dict(key)
    Next key
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly my thinking ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim fruits As Variant
    Dim i As Long, y As Long, count As Long, LastRow As Long

    fruits = Array("banana", "orange", "apple", "orange", "apple", "orange")

    For i = LBound(fruits) To UBound(fruits)

        count = 0

        For y = LBound(fruits) To UBound(fruits)

            If fruits(i) = fruits(y) Then

                count = count + 1

            End If

        Next y

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), fruits(i)) = 0 Then
                .Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Value = fruits(i)
                .Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Value = count
            End If

        End With

    Next i

End Sub
```

**Results(Sheet 1, Columns A & B):**

[image]